# Becoming a superuser postgresql

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

How do i make myself a superuser on postgresql?

I keep trying to create a database and I keep getting the following errors:

> createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database

I'm guessing this is because i'm not a superuser but i don't know what's wrong. 
Here's what i did:

```
> sudo su postgres

> postgres@precise64:/xxx/xxx/projectfile$createuser -P
> Enter name of role to add: vagrantUser
> Enter password: 
> Enter it again:
> Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
> postgres@precise64:/vagrant/django_projects/mblog$ psql -U vagrantUser template1
> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "vagrantUser"
> postgres@precise64:/vagrant/django_projects/mblog$ exit
> (venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/project$:psql template1
> template1 =# \q
> (venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/project$:createdb mydb
```

I get the following error:

> createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database

Pleae help

Answer (score 5):

Long story short - you don't want vagrant to be superuser. instead, make the vagrant database from postgres account, and make it's owner (i.e. the database) vagrant user.

Comment: Thanks @depesz. How do i do that?

Comment: using psql, from postgres shell account, connect to database, and issue: `create database vagrant with owner vagrant`, or however you want the db/user named.

Answer (score 0):

The createuser script takes a "--createdb" option to allow the new user to create databases (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-createuser.html).
You did not specify this, so "vagrantUser" cannot create new databases.

Having said that, @depesz makes a good point - it's best practice to have a single superuser/root database account and use that to create/maintain databases, create separate accounts for databases and grant appropriate permissions to those accounts; but I was totally focused on the problem =)