# Cannot run rake db:migrate, relation does not exist

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ubuntu-10.04, vagrant

I am trying to get a working app to work on linux 10.04 running on vagrant

I installed all relevant gems, installed postgresql 9.1.9 and when I am trying to run
`rake db:migrate` I am getting

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "messages" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"messages"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"messages"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec_no_cache'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.1.26/Ruby/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:246:in `log_with_miniprofiler'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record.rb:36:in `block in log_with_newrelic_instrumentation'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:235:in `trace_execution_scoped'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record.rb:33:in `log_with_newrelic_instrumentation'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1286:in `column_definitions'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `columns'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'

/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:237:in `columns_hash'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:19:in `descends_from_active_record?'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:25:in `finder_needs_type_condition?'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:455:in `relation'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:37:in `scoped'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `where'
/home/vagrant/myapp/app/models/message.rb:29:in `<class:Message>'
/home/vagrant/myapp/app/models/message.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/acts-as-messageable-0.4.8/lib/acts-as-messageable/model.rb:34:in `acts_as_messageable'
/home/vagrant/myapp/app/models/user.rb:123:in `<class:User>'
/home/vagrant/myapp/app/models/user.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise.rb:272:in `get'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise.rb:306:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise.rb:306:in `add_mapping'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
/home/vagrant/myapp/config/routes.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `instance_exec'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `eval_block'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `draw'
/home/vagrant/myapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/vagrant/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

running `rake db:create:all` tells me all tables have already been created

I don't know if it matters or not, but I am using devise 2.2.4 and latest acts_as_messageable.

note that this app does work on a windows development machine and production in heroku.. I just want to make it run on vagrant as well..

my database.yml is

```
common: &common

      adapter: postgresql
      enconding: utf8
      host: localhost
      username: postgres
      password: 1234
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
    development:
      <<: *common
      database: myapp_dev
      port: 5432
    test:
      <<: *common
      database: myapp_test

    production:
      <<: *common
      database: myapp_prod
```

I suspect it has to do with some postgres configuration, but I am not sure.. Couldn't find any solution to this yet

When checking psql I get this

```
postgres=# \l
                                   List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 myapp_dev  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 myapp_prod | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 myapp_test | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
(6 rows)

postgres=# \d myapp_dev
Did not find any relation named "myapp_dev".
```

so something is wrong here I think.. is there a solution?

Note - this happens with `rake db` tasks such as `schema:load`, `setup`..

In case this is needed - here are the relevant lines from the error relating to acts_as_messageable, including the migration file

user: line 120-123

```
acts_as_messageable :table_name => "messages", 
                    :required   => :body,               
                    :class_name => "Message",     
                    :dependent  => :destroy
```

Message class (line 25-29)

```
class Message < ActsAsMessageable::Message

attr_accessible :sender_open, :reciever_open
scope :unread_by, lambda{ |user| where("reciever_open = false AND received_messageable_id = ?", user.id)}
scope :unread, where('reciever_open = false')
```

the migration file - 20121127082447_create_messages_table.rb (its not first or last, somewhere in the middle)

```
class CreateMessagesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :topic
      t.text :body
      t.references :received_messageable, :polymorphic => true
      t.references :sent_messageable, :polymorphic => true
      t.boolean :opened, :default => false
      t.boolean :recipient_delete, :default => false
      t.boolean :sender_delete, :default => false
      t.timestamps

      # ancestry
      t.string :ancestry
    end

    add_index :messages, [:sent_messageable_id, :received_messageable_id], :name => "acts_as_messageable_ids"
    add_index :messages, :ancestry
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :messages
  end
end
```

Comment: Does your messages table even exist? Any odds that your search path is erroneous, that you're using the wrong DB, or something to that order?

Comment: it doesn't exist yet, since I can't migrate at all..

Comment: In this case, wouldn't that indicate some kind of flow error in your own code, or in the code of the plugin you're using? Perhaps make the migration in two separate steps or something?

Comment: the thing is that this migration works well in heroku and in the windows machine

Comment: Mm... Any odds you can manage to log what the migration is doing, query by query? `::regclass` will yield the first table that matches in your `search_path`, so it might be that the migration is merely catering to something it shouldn't at one point on the machines where it works, with no subsequent impact due to the queries returning correct column names regardless.

Comment: Another thing that might be happening is if the whole thing gets prepared before it gets executed. If the messages table already exists, `'"messages"'::regclass` then gets expanded as needed. But if it's created earlier in the statement that is getting prepared, then you'd get a relation does not exist error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Routes` file in Rails uses `device_for`, which loads the User model, which in turn has `acts_as_messagable` and loads the `Message` class. Line #29 in `Message` class says:

`scope :unread, where('reciever_open = false')`

The `where` method is triggering a column lookup, which fails because the migrations haven't run yet! Try one of these two:

Change this to:

`scope :unread, where(:reciever_open => false)`

Or if that also triggers a column lookup, then say:

`scope :unread, lambda { where('reciever_open = false') }`

Comment: Thank you. This saved lot of my time. Any idea, why this happens only in case of boolean field, I have other scopes based on other columns, but those are not creating any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to check on the obvious here, but have you tried running `rake db:drop`?  Whenever I make changes to my migrations, I need to drop all of my DB tables before I try to create and migrate them.

So the full operation would be `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Oh, and you can also try to specify the environment (I sometimes need to do that on test environments), e.g. `rake RAILS_ENV=test db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: tried that and it didn't work.. drop works, create works and migrate doesn't

Comment: Are you just using the default "postgres" user to log in and create tables in PostgreSQL?  You should try creating a separate username/password with the appropriate permissions and using that.

I saw this link about using Vagrant and Postgres together (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831173/becoming-a-superuser-postgresql) - you may need to set vagrant as an owner on your database.

Comment: but the database is created, if I check with pgpadmin (after installing gnome,etc) I see the 3 databases, but the schema is not being created. Also I gave postgres and vagrant the same permissions to pretty much do everything.

Comment: Ok.  Well, you said that the command `\d myapp_dev` fails, as it cannot find the table.  Can you try it with quotes really quick?  So `\d "myapp_dev"`

Comment: some response, doesn't find it.. hmph