# Validation creating error during postgresql migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-postgresql

I'm migrating an app from rails 2.3 to rails 3. I'm planning on moving to heroku, so I'm also moving to postgres.

I have a model which has lots of fields - about 30.  I want to validate the completion of all of these fields, except 2. In my rails 2 app I had:

```
validates_presence_of (self.column_names - ["id", "email_not_name"]), :on => :update
```

This worked, and in fact works in Rails3 as well.  The problem comes when I try to run the migrations for the new database - I get the "PGError: ERROR: relation “*table_name*” does not exist" error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583531/cannot-run-rake-dbmigrate-relation-does-not-exist). Not sure why this doesn't occur with SQLite3, but it doesn't really matter.

If I remove the validation, the migrations run fine - the problem is that none of the self.column_names actually exist yet. Similarly, if I change the migration to

```
validates_presence_of :field1, :field2, :on => :update
```

the migration will run without problems.  Clearly, I could just list all 30 fields, but this strikes me as clumsy and not very maintainable. What I really want is:

```
validates :all, :except=>:email_not_name, :presence=>true, :on => :update
```

but unfortunately that doesn't actually exist! Is there a way that I can do this without resorting to this? (either rails2 or rails3 style)

**Answer:**

Ok, so for anyone who comes across this, here's how to do this. The solution is to create a custom error handler, called with:

validate :check_all_questions_completed,  :on => :update

The error handler itself is:

```
def check_all_questions_completed
 Person.column_names.each do |col|
  if (Person.column_names - ["id", "email_not_name"]).include?(col) && send(col).nil?
   errors.add(col)
  end
 aend
end
```

If anyone can tidy up my code, please do (the model concerned is Person)